# How to programmatically get available TCP port on remote IIS

Tags: iis

I need to install web site on remote IIS.
But before doing that I need to find available TCP port on remote IIS.
I managed to find the code that makes this locally only.

What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: This isn't at all suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot tell which port is available remotely; I would imagine your best approach is to run something on the remote server which finds an available port number and then to transfer this port (somehow) back to the server doing the remote install.

Comment: Yes. I thought about it. For example, I could use WCF-service in this case. But I'm not sure customer will agree to install additional software. Any way, thanks for reply...